# How to use React Hooks to capture the last input letter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning React Hooks, and I wanna to build a type race game: a mini game to track how quickly you can type out a snippet of text.

The logic is simple: When user starts the game, set the `start time`, and when the `value` of the input equals the chosen `snippet`, display the `endTime`.

But when I start the game and input the correct words, it doesn't show that I have input the same words.

Open the console, input any words, and I found that **react did not capture the last letter I have input**, for example, I input `abc`, the console just show me `ab`.

So how can I **use react hooks** to complete the game?

Here is my whole code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const SNIPPETS = [
    'Bears, beets, battlestar galactica',
    "What's Forrest Gump's password? 1Forrest1",
    'Where do programmers like to hangout? The Foo Bar'
  ]

  const INITIAL_GAME_STATE = { victory: false, startTime: null, endTime: null }

  const [snippet, setSnippet] = useState('')
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(INITIAL_GAME_STATE)
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('change')
    if (gameState.victory) {
      document.title = gameState.victory ? 'Victory!' : 'Playing...'
    }
  }, [gameState.victory])

  const updateUserText = e => {
    setUserText(e.target.value)
    console.log(snippet)
    console.log(userText)
    if (userText === snippet) {
      console.log('same')
      setGameState({
        ...gameState,
        victory: true,
        endTime: new Date().getTime() - gameState.startTime
      })
    }
  }

  const chooseSnippet = snippetIndex => () => {
    setSnippet(SNIPPETS[snippetIndex])
    setGameState({
      ...gameState,
      startTime: new Date().getTime()
    })
  } 

  return (
    <div className="game-wrapper">
      <h2>Type Race</h2>
      { snippet && (
        <>
          <h4>{ snippet }</h4>
          <input type="textarea" value={ userText } onChange={ updateUserText } />
          <br />
        </>
      ) }
      <br/>
      <button onClick={ chooseSnippet(0) }>Start a new race!</button>
      <br/>
      { gameState.victory && (
        <h4>`Done! <span></span>Time: ${ gameState.endTime }ms`</h4>
      ) }
      <br/>
      {
        SNIPPETS.map((SNIPPET, index) => (
          <button onClick={ chooseSnippet(index) } key={ index }>
            { SNIPPET.substring(0, 10) }...
          </button>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because React setState is asynchronous, so your `userText` value will not be updated after you call `setUserText`. To get an updated `userText`, wait for the next rendering of the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userText === snippet) {
    // do something ...    
  }
}, [userText]);
```

For more information: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

just as Trí Phan answered, `setState` is asynchronous in hooks too.
so I fixed it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (userText === snippet && userText) {
      setGameState({
        ...gameState,
        victory: true,
        endTime: new Date().getTime() - gameState.startTime
      })
    }
  }, [userText])
```